# OAuth - Tuple object is not callable

Tags: python, oauth, tuples

The below works fine and can be used across tests

```
f = open('creds.json')
creds = json.load(f)

def get_access_token(url, client_id, client_secret):
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "api://xyz.default"},
        auth=(client_id, client_secret),
    )
    return response.json()["access_token"]

new_token = get_access_token(creds["auth_url"],client_id=creds["client_id"], client_secret=creds["client_secret"])
headers = {"loggedInUsername": "Test, User","Content-Type":"application/json",'Authorization': f"Bearer {new_token}"}
```

However, we just changed authentication method parameters to use `username` and `password` instead of `client_secret`. The parameters provided work fine in Postman, but the following is throwing `'Tuple object is not callable'` across the `pytest` test files.

Is it something about having 3 `auth` parameters instead of 2?

```
def get_access_token(url, client_id, username, password):
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"grant_type": "password", "scope": "api://xyz.default"},
        auth=(client_id, username, password),
    )
    return response.json()["access_token"]

new_token = get_access_token(creds["auth_url"],client_id=creds["client_id"], username=creds["username"], password=creds["password"])
headers = {"loggedInUsername": "Test, User","Content-Type":"application/json",'Authorization': f"Bearer {new_token}"}
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/) it should be `auth=(username, password)`. There shouldn't be a client ID.

Comment: Your old configuration was just using the client ID and secret as username and password. The syntax doesn't change, just the values.

Comment: When I leave client_id out in Postman it throws: 'The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'

Comment: That says the body, not the header. It's supposed to be in the `data`.

Comment: Thank you! Although I had to move the client_id, username and password into data but it did eventually work.  I am surprised the old way even worked at all.  Thanks again